# Why I can't access my script variable from class?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

As topic says. I can't access variable from class made in same script.
It's in same script, and variables(as you see) are public. Any ideas?
Tried googling "how to access script variable from another class" but didn't found anything.

Code:

```
public var Ludnosc = new Array();
var humanCount : int;

public class Human {
    public var id : byte;
    public var creatureType = "HUMAN";
    public var gender : boolean; // false = k, true = m
    //public var firstname : String; <- Opcja do wprowadzenia później
    //public var lastname : String; <- Opcja do wprowadzenia później
    public var age : byte;
    public var pregnant : boolean = false;
    function Breed(partner) {
        if(this.age<16) {
        Debug.Log("Woman with id " + this.id + " is too young to be pregnant. She must be 16 or older.");
        }
        else {
            var success = Random.Range(0.0, makePregnantChance);
            Debug.Log("Breed chance of partners with IDs [" + this.id + ", " + partner + "] was " + success*100 + "%.");
            if(success>0.50) {
                this.pregnant = true;
                Debug.Log("Creature of type " + this.creatureType + ", with ID " + this.id + " is pregnant!");
                Ludnosc.push(new Human()); //LINE 44 | tworzymy nowego czlowieczka
                var tempHuman = Ludnosc[humanCount+1] as Human //LINE 45
                tempHuman.id = humanCount+1; //LINE 46
                tempHuman.age = 1;
                var losujPlec = Random.Range(0.0, 1.0);
                tempHuman.makePregnantChance = 18/tempHuman.age;
                }
            }
    }
    public var parents : byte[]; //Najpierw podajemy ID matki, potem ID ojca.
    public var makePregnantChance : float;
}
```

Bugs:

```
Assets/TextPierwszy.js(44,33): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'Ludnosc'.
Assets/TextPierwszy.js(45,49): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'Ludnosc'.
Assets/TextPierwszy.js(45,57): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'humanCount'.
Assets/TextPierwszy.js(46,48): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'humanCount'.
```

Comment: `public var Ludnosc = new Array();
var humanCount : int;` must be declared inside the class

Comment: Maybe you should have some sort of HumanManager class that does the breeding logic. The Human class could still determine the success etc, but the Manager class would actually add the new human to the array. Side note, check your logic for mating chance success. I don't think it will work how you want it to.

Comment: @Christian Code for mating isn't finished. I encountered problem while writing it(adding new _Human_ via function of _Human_ class). That's why it looks so weird.

Comment: @user2320445 I think this will actually be the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code here:

```
public var Ludnosc = new Array();
var humanCount : int;

public class Human {...
```

Needs to actually be:

```
public class Human {
    public var Ludnosc = new Array();
    var humanCount : int;
```

That is of course, if they're related to the class, if not, then you'll be better off creating another class to hold anything else `HumanExtras` (or something similar),for example.

Comment: The same answer as to @user2320445 : this solution be best in my opinion. Creating new class just for listing humans is no sense. Thanks guys for your response!

Comment: @DawidUrbanowicz This will work but it seems strange to have a class hold an array of its own type. Also look into design patterns like Factory. I know it's more code but it is best investment in the long run. Depends really on if this is a pet project or commercial.

Comment: @Christian Yes, I know. I saw this at moment of coding this _solution_. I made them statics in new class and it works flawlessy. And thanks, I'll check this pattern. It's always nice to learn new things that can help make my work easier and less affected by problems.

Comment: So creating a new class to hold these did make sense in the end then? ;)